# Inserting records into a table from an element

Tags: cakephp

I have an element that i am calling with a view file. The element is a add view that is add.ctp, challenge that im having now is that the element is not inserting form input into the table (it_query_responses).

here is how i am calling my element within the view -

```
<?php echo $this->Element('ItQueryResponses/add'); ?>
```

and here is the code for the element

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQueryResponse'); ?>
<legend><?php echo __('Add It Query Response'); ?></legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('it_query_id');
echo $this->Form->input('hr_employee_id');
echo $this->Form->input('response');
echo $this->Form->input('it_query_status_id');
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

and here is add function in ItQueryResponsesController

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->ItQueryResponse->create();
if ($this->ItQueryResponse->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query response has been saved'));
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query response could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
}
$itQueries = $this->ItQueryResponse->ItQuery->find('list');
$hrEmployees = $this->ItQueryResponse->HrEmployee->find('list');
$itQueryStatuses = $this->ItQueryResponse->ItQueryStatus->find('list');
$this->set(compact('itQueries', 'hrEmployees', 'itQueryStatuses'));
}
```

Comment: have you write save() function using model ?

Comment: http://speakingofcomputers.blogspot.in/2012/01/cakephp-how-to-update-and-insert-data.html Please refer this

Comment: @Dolly i have added the add function, not sure what i must change in the code.

Comment: Are there any validation rules defined for the `ItQueryResponse` model?

Comment: What is the view file that you are actually rendering? From what you are telling us, you seem to render `view.ctp` and from within this you're rendering the `ItQueryResponses/add.ctp` element. Is that correct? If this is the case then you must specify an `action` to the `create()` method of the `FormHelper`, otherwise the default action is the same as your view.

Comment: @CrisSawfish yes you are correct. I have specified the action to the create() method of the FormHelper like this - <?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQueryResponse'); ?>

Comment: @dhofstet yes every field is validated not to be empty

Comment: Your `create()` method should be like this: `$this->Form->create('ItQueryResponse', array('action' => 'add'));`, otherwise the form submits to the `view()` method of your controller.

Comment: @CrisSawfish u simply the best....it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it did... Keep in mind a simple rule, until you get the feeling of cakephp. `Controller::somemethod()` should have a respective `/View/Controller/somemethod.ctp` view file. This way cakephp handles everything smoothly and you don't have to worry about anything. Otherwise you will have to specify everything on your own...